# Quarkus Native on GraalVM issue with ElasticSearch Java Client jakarta.json.JsonException: Provider org.eclipse.parsson.JsonProviderImpl not found

Tags: elasticsearch, quarkus, graalvm, elasticsearch-java-api, quarkus-native

I'm using Quarkus *2.16.6.Final* with ElasticSearch *8.7*. I've written a small piece of code to use ES's update_by_query feature.

```
try (Reader query = new StringReader(/*my json query String*/)) {
  var request = UpdateByQueryRequest.of(fn -> fn.index(index).withJson(query));

  return client.updateByQuery(request);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

And this is my ES client initialization code:

```
var credsProv = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

credsProv.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

var restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(host)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(
    hc -> hc.disableAuthCaching().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProv)).build();

var transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

var client = new ElasticsearchAsyncClient(transport);
```

This actually works fine in normal jvm mode. However whenever I'm trying to run this is **Quarkus Native**(GraalVM) mode I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: jakarta.json.JsonException: Provider org.eclipse.parsson.JsonProviderImpl not found
at jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider.newInstance(JsonProvider.java:160)
at jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:144)
at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpUtils.findProvider(JsonpUtils.java:65)
... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.parsson.JsonProviderImpl
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1105)
    at jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider.newInstance(JsonProvider.java:157)
```

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/installation.html), I've added required dependency in the **Maven** pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
                <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
        <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But that didn't solve this issue and wondering how come the same thing works on normal JVM but not in native mode in GraalVM

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I resolved by replacing the JSON-P API and provider dependencies which I was using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

with this Quarkus dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jsonp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```